# Using a for loop to add sum of numbers from a .txt file

Tags: for-loop, python-3.4, readfile, accumulator

I'm trying to add the sum of all numbers from a text file and print out all numbers that were added.
Text file includes 9,5,9,7,11.  The numbers are on separate lines.  The total is 41, but my code keeps printing 52.
The output should look like:
9 5 9 7 11. Your total is: 41

```
    def main():
    # Open a file for reading.
    infile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')




    total = 0
    for line in infile:
        amount = int(line)
        total += amount








    total += int(line.strip())




    infile.close()




    print(line)
    print('Your total is:',total)







main()
```

Comment: "The total is 41, but my code keeps printing 52.
The output should look like: 9 5 9 7 11. Your total is: 41"

41+11 = 52. You add 11 two times.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? This seems like "homework"

Comment: If you tidy up your code a little bit, deleting all the extra blank lines, the answer will be apparent. Also, proof that python's syntax can't actually enforce readability :/

Comment: remove that line you are adding twice 11 as @Spoe said total += int(line.strip())

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to this and was spinning in circles after reviewing my code trying to figure it out what extra I left in there.  That was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
total = 0
for line in infile:
    amount = int(line)
    total += amount
infile.close()
print(line)
print('Your total is:',total)
```

No need of using this line

```
total += int(line.strip())
```

Now your program works correctly.